# Как исправить код что б метод объекта Point работал правильно

Tags: javascript, объекты, методы

Нужно определить в какой декартовой системе координат находится точка вводимая от пользователя х и у

```
var point = {
    x: +prompt("Введите координат Х"),
    y: +prompt("Введите координат У"),
}
    point.getQuadrant = function(x, y, result){
        switch(result){
            case x >= 0 || y >= 0 :
                result = "I";
                break;
            case x < 0 || y > 0 :
                result = "II";
                break;
            case x < 0 || y < 0 :
                result = "III";
                break;
            case x > 0 || y < 0 :
                result = "IV";
                break;
            default :
                result ="Попробуйте еще раз";
        }
}
alert("Точка находится в " + point.getQuadrant() + " системе координат")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то в таком случае нужно, во-первых, использовать операторы `if`, а во-вторых, формировать условия с логическим И `&&` или использовать комбинацию `if` и тернарного оператора:

```js
point.getQuadrant = function() {
    if (this.x >= 0) {
        return this.y >= 0 ? "I" : "IV";
    }
    return this.y >= 0 ? "II" : "III";
}
```

Более сокращенная форма с тернарными операторами:

```js
point.getQuadrant = function() {
    return this.x >= 0 ? (this.y >= 0 ? "I" : "IV" ) : (this.y >= 0 ? "II" : "III");
}
```

Comment: может что-то не так понял но теперь всё время ответ III на выходе

Comment: Нужно было добавить `this` для полей внутри метода, или вызывать метод, передавая параметры: `point.getQuadrant(point.x, point.y)`